# How to scale multiple objects on a given axis?

Tags: modeling, transforms

I made a simple model of a house *(fig.1)* .
Now, I want to copy the house and mirror it **negative 1** on the **Y-axi**s in **global orientation**.

It should give me an exact mirrored copy of the original but instead all of the different objects get flipped in unwanted directions *(fig.2)* .

The house contains multiple objects (roofing, windows, doors, etc.)

I've run into this problem once or twice in the past but did not find a solution or why this is happening, nor could I replicate it in a clean blendfile.

*(I know about the **transformation orientation** settings as well as the different options to set the **pivoting point** of one or multiple objects.)*

Does someone know why this is happening?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent the duplicates to an Empty and then scale that empty by -1 on one axis.

Comment: Nice tip, thanks! This way I can apply the scale and rotation after I mirrored the objects. only thing to keep in mind, as always: flip the normals :)

Answer (score 0):

Before mirroring, apply rotation and scale to all of your objects <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however I can not apply the rotation and scale because some objects are linked duplicates (ALT+D) .
This should not make a difference as the transformation orientation is set to 'Global' right?

Comment: It makes the difference: you should apply rotation and scale to the original source objects (and it's a good habit to always apply rotation and scale after modeling, exactely to avoid this kind of problems).

Comment: There is a workaround: if an object is rotated 30 deg on the X axis you can set the rotation to 0, make the mirroring, then set the X rotation to - 30.

Comment: The workaround solves all rotation issues, To bad that I have to do this manually for all objects where the rotation is not zero. Guess I have to figure out a new workflow for future projects. It still blows my mind that the Global orientation does not affect this.