# Can I rotate multiple bones at once LOCALLY, without unparenting every single one?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I'm currently having to rotate the bone rolls of my armature like [this.](https://my.mixtape.moe/vfrnqo.webm)

I have to rotate it the same way for all the arm bones, all the leg bones, etc.

In 3DSMax, you can select local rotation and rotate multiple bones at once, however, in Blender, [this happens.](https://my.mixtape.moe/hfihbu.webm)

Does anyone know of a way to rotate these bones so I can switch their axis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Pivot point: individual origins - it's the icon beside the shading selector and the 3d manipulator icon. Select individual Origins.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd>  with all bones you want rotate selected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Was used to Maya where selecting multiple bones (or control points) and rotating would rotate them all via individual origins. Press `.` (period key) to select *Individual Origins*. Tehn, you can also press `R`, `R` to rotate them freely (trackball style), which may be useful for new users to know.

Answer (score 0):

Well i had the same problem. Select bones in pose mode and change transformations from translate to rotate. Obviously there is skewed logic behind, as you cant translate bones in pose mode, only rotate them based on their pivot.

Comment: What does "there is skewed logic behind" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your link is now dead for me, but it sounds like you want to adjust the rest-pose roll of your bones.

The best way to do this for multiple bones at once is to use the recalculate roll operation (ctrl n in edit mode for me), which can work on any number of bones at once.  You'll see a number of options to set these to attempt to align to global axes, or to tangent axes (which requires that the bones have children.)  There's also the option to point the Z axis of the bones at the cursor.

Another way to adjust roll is in pose mode.  You can rotate a bone in pose mode, then ctrl-a (apply) -> apply selected as rest pose to adjust the roll of a bone.  Unfortunately, even individual origins uses a median axis for the bones, so this isn't necessarily a great way to adjust the bone rolls of multiple bones at once.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the origin.I don't know you setup.You can also make the rotation to one, and paste it to all the others.

Comment: How would I paste the rotation to the other bones?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/how-do-i-copy-a-property-from-an-active-object-to-selected-objects or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70547/how-to-scale-multiple-objects-on-a-given-axis

Comment: So I'm trying to figure out how to do this for bones? I can do it for Objects, but I must be missing something with bones?

Comment: You can't manipulate bones as objects?You can check if there is copy local, I don't remember, also in tab (with the plus sighn) that is right from the 3d view there are the local dimensions

Comment: well, if i select the bone in object mode, it selects the whole armature.

sorry if i'm missing something really really obvious, i'm really new to trying this stuff.

Comment: Do it on edit mode.

Comment: Right, so just to be clear.

Enable the plugin.
Select my rotated bone.
Hit Control + C
Shift select the other bones, and hit space and type in paste rotations?

Comment: I personally use the build in copy attribute to selected

Comment: Could you send some screenshots? I can't seem to find it for some reason in edit mode. Sorry to ask so much :(

Comment: I found also this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74362/how-do-i-rotate-bones-along-bone-axis

Comment: I can do that, I just can't do that on multiple bones at once.

Comment: Ah, you can use pivot points -> individual origins. But I'm still wondering about that bone rotation thing as it'd be really useful.

Comment: Maybe you can use a script, As I show you can't rotate as long as they are parented.Except maybe if you go from the bottom in the parent hierarchy to the top